# Iterating if loop based on the result or conditions of the sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, if-statement, 3-tier

Okay here is my code

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (bll.MainEnq_Stu_Name(en) != null)
    {
        Label9.Text = bll.MainEnq_Stu_Name(en).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        Label9.Text = "No Records Found!";
    }  
}
```

here is the query in the business logic layer.

```
  //MainEnquiry.aspx panel1
    public object MainEnq_Stu_Name(EntityLayer.Entity en)
    {
        return dll.GetSingleValue("select name from studentinfo where mobile=" + en.mainEnq_Stu_Mobile+"and dob is not null");
    }
```

[image: here is the screen shot of the table in db.]

now what i want to do is to add one more functionality to if iteration in my code above.

```
that is if mobile is null print "no records found".
and if dob is not null print "this user already exists"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include columns which are required in your case its name,mobile and dob.
So first do this

```
//MainEnquiry.aspx panel1
public object MainEnq_Stu_Name(EntityLayer.Entity en)
{
    return dll.GetSingleValue("select name,mobile,dob from studentinfo where mobile=" + en.mainEnq_Stu_Mobile+"and dob is not null");
}
```

Then just else if conditions in your code. Hope you can go from here.

Comment: although i have to make a lot of changes in the previous code but yes your code worked  ... nevertheless  a big thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement in your SQL select statement. But I don't know if the following is what you want to do. Do you want to return the three columns or just one?

```
    //MainEnquiry.aspx panel1
    public object MainEnq_Stu_Name(EntityLayer.Entity en)
    {
        return dll.GetSingleValue("select case when mobile is null then 'no records found' when dob is null then 'this user already exists' else name end from studentinfo where mobile=" + en.mainEnq_Stu_Mobile+"and dob is not null");
    }
```